# open word document corrupt

Tags: c#, asp.net, office-interop

I'm trying to send a Word document (generated in ASP .NET server and Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word) to client side, but everytime I try to open in client side using IE9, it says that it can't open it because it's corrupt, but if I try to save it and open it, it works fine. So where's the problem?

Here's the code:

```
        string nombreDoc = @"C:\tempDocs\Test.doc";
        generateIndex(nombreDoc); //this is an internal operation using Interop.Word
        FileStream sourceFile = new FileStream(nombreDoc, FileMode.Open);
        float FileSize;
        FileSize = sourceFile.Length;
        byte[] getContent = new byte[(int)FileSize];
        sourceFile.Read(getContent, 0, (int)sourceFile.Length);
        sourceFile.Close();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetNoServerCaching();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-word.document";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", getContent.Length.ToString());
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Test.doc");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(getContent);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        File.Delete(nombreDoc);
```

I have tried to use WriteFile instead of BynaryWrite and the problem persists.

Comment: Is the `Content-Length` correct ? (try to remove it for test). Did you also gzip the response file ? (if you do , then the Content-Length is not correct). (The Content-Length, is what you send, not necessary the size of the file)

Comment: Problem persists not using Content-Length (as I have realised GZip is enabled).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually because your server has output compression enabled. Basically, your server is trying to GZip the binary document before writing to the output stream. Google will show you how to verify if compression is turned on and how to disable it if it is.

Comment: I have tried to disable GZIP compression on IIS Express (because I am testing now) doing the following commands: 1- Start Command Prompt 2- I go to (%programfiles%\iis express) 3- I execute the following command: appcmd set config -section:urlCompression /doDynamicCompression:false and I have tried again but the problem persists!! So what's going?

Comment: If you can verify that it IS in fact disabled, then it's probably not compression. Although compression is USUALLY the problem.

Comment: I have realised that the problem only occurs on IE9, if I try is on Mozilla Firefox it works fine! (without changes) So what do I have to take in mind for IE users?

Comment: Not sure. If you know what the problem is, as well as the solution, then a simple test for browser name + version should be sufficient.

Comment: I have accomplished to make it work in IE9 after chaging this line: HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Test.doc"); to HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=Test.doc"); Could someone let me know why?

Comment: I would imagine it's because IE9 expects an attachment to be encoded differently from an inline document? Pure speculation.

Answer (score 1):

Change the content type to octet-stream, and revert to using WriteFile instead of BinaryWrite

```
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
```

Comment: Problem persists using octet-stream :(

Comment: I'm using almost identical code in one of my applications and it is working correctly, hence I would look next at server settings as per the answer from @JuannStrauss. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

All though my reply might not answer your question completely, but I had been with another problem with ASP.Net & Office Automation.
I learned the hard way that its not recommended:
[Microsoft support](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;q257757#kb2)

What I did was I made a Windows service instead, which used to create a Word document like the way you are trying to do and make a file on server.
The Service would then write the path of the file in database & ASP.Net page will send that file for download. Basically, avoid Office Automation via ASP.Net

Comment: I tried at first avoiding Office Automation in ASP. NET because of the security reasons, but the problem is that I couldn't find any external library which could open a HTML file and generate an TOC (Table of contents) based on the Headind styles. That's the reason I finally used Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word...